# PostgreSQL - tuning multiple clusters in one server

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I usually use http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/ for tuning postgresql parameters depending on hardware resources.

But now I want to tune two clusters on same server.

How should I tune PostgreSQL configuration in this case?

For the sake of simplicity let say both clusters would be under similar load.

Now with this setup:

```
DB Version: 10
OS Type: Linux
DB Type: Online transaction processing systems
RAM: 2 GB
Number of CPUs: 2
Data Storage: SSD
```

`pgtune.leopard` recommends this configuration:

```
max_connections = 300
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 1536MB
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 1747kB
min_wal_size = 2GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 2
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 1
max_parallel_workers = 2
```

So do I need to "slice" parameters in half or generally just use suggested configuration for each cluster? Or maybe it is recommended to use some different strategy here?

Comment: I think you need to go on this site for this type of question : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql. You have a little more chance to get an answers to this type of questions in there ;)

Comment: @Jaisus just did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much you can configure here. The exceptions are:

- `shared_buffers`, `work_mem` and `max_connections`: these three determine your memory usage. You need to divide `shared_buffers` and `max_connections` or `work_mem` between the clusters.
- `effective_cache_size`: split that as well.
- `effective_io_concurrency` should be split as well.

Most resources cannot be controlled effectively from the configuration. You may want to give [`pg_cgroups`](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_cgroups) a try (disclaimer: I am the author).